# How to get sum of input values selection by id (0 to n) using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sum of input value selection by ids. id is incrementing by 1. I know it is very easy with class selector and each function. But I am searching for id.

```
<input type="number"  value="10.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-0-inputqty">
<input type="number"  value="12.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-1-inputqty">
<input type="number"  value="14.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-2-inputqty">
<input type="number"  value="16.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-3-inputqty">
```

Output should be 52.

Comment: `$('[id^="id_inputformset-"][id$="-inputqty"]')` .. `^` means starts with `$` means ends with

Comment: `I know it is very easy with class selector and each function` then why not use a class? Incremental id attributes are very rarely a good idea

Comment: i am using djnago crispy form, and  this out of html generated by it, There are other type of input with same class,Which i don't want to include in sum.

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef please add your comment to answer as this is what i want.
i would like to accept this as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `each` and sum all `float values` The `parseFloat() function` parses an argument (converting it to a string first if needed) and returns a `floating point number`.

```js
let sum = 0;
$('[id^=id_inputformset]').each(function(e){
 sum +=parseFloat($(this).val());
})

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number"  value="10.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-0-inputqty">
<input type="number"  value="12.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-1-inputqty">
<input type="number"  value="14.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-2-inputqty">
<input type="number"  value="16.0" class="numberinput form-control" id="id_inputformset-3-inputqty">
```